# Play Store Country Distribution (Publishing)

Tags: android, publishing

After 10 months of development, I am all set to release my first app!!!. I was going through the publishing checklist, can anyone confirm if the country distribution can be modified after you publish your app.

I would like to do a limited release to US only and then expand to other countries. Is that possible? BTW my app is free.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#countries

Thank you!

-L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be modified after publishing.

The only two things that can't be modified are:

1. Package name of the app
2. Paid state - You can't make a paid app free, and a free app paid. You can adjust the price of a paid app.

Comment: You can't change the keystore to sign your app too