# Want to edit App distribution country list in google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Hi I uploaded Android Application on Google play and select US as a distribution country. Now I want to edit it and want to add India also in the list. How to make changes?

Comment: your question is about `how to use google play developer console web site`, not related to programming

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko your moderation would be more helpful if you suggested an alternative forum to post this question.  If one doesn't exist, then this is an appropriate place to post it...

Answer (score 18):

Go to the main side menu -> *Release* -> *Production*. It opens a new page. There are three tabs...  The last tab is *Countries/regions* .  Then you can see Add and Remove countries/regions option on the right side colored gray.

[image]

Comment: It will get reviewed and published by Google Team. It is not automatic.

Answer (score 10):

Follow this [support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en) on how to edit app's availability:

> **App availability**
>
> App availability refers to your app's availability in the production track. When you select a country as available, any future production releases include that country.
>
> To manage your app's availability:
>
> 1. Go to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
> 2. Select an app.
> 3. Select **Store presence > Pricing & distribution**.
> 4. In the "Countries" section, select **Manage countries**.
> 5. Update your app's country selection.
>
>    - If you add a country for a paid app, new prices are automatically added. If needed, you can then [edit local prices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373#price_multiple).
> 6. Submit your app update.
>
> **Note**: For details on how to target a staged rollout to specific countries, go to [release app updates with staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149#staged_country).

You may also check this thread, [Play Store Country Distribution (Publishing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910740/play-store-country-distribution-publishing), which stated that it can be modified after publishing.

Comment: Can I make Alpha track available in say Australia and Japan, but make Production available only in Japan?

Comment: It seems that support page information is not correct.  There is no "Pricing & distribution" option under "Store presence".  The answer below (go to "Release -> Production") appears to be the correct one.